# SCP command fails to copy "Host key verification failed."

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I am new to Jenkins pipeline and I am trying to copy the file from one AWS Jenkins server to another AWS server. Both are Ubuntu servers. When I am running scp command in command line in Jenkins server it copies the file from the Jenkins server to destination server but in Jenkins pipeline it it showing "Host key Verification failed". What mistake I am doing ?

pipeline stage is

```
  stage('Deliver') {
        steps {
            sh 'scp -i /home/ubuntu/connec/new_one.pem **/target/*.jar ubuntu@00.00.000.00:/home/ubuntu'
        }
    }
```

error is

```
 scp -i /home/ubuntu/connec/new_one.pem **/target/*.jar ubuntu@00.000.00.00:/home/ubuntu

 Host key verification failed.

 lost connection

 script returned exit code 1
```

****Solved i have posted as a answer what i did. please suggest if i am wrong. Thanks ****

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*scp -v* is you friend here. This is the verbose flag for scp.

I suspect that the user you are testing with on the box and the user that Jenkins runs as are two different users, so the initial key exchange has never happened for the Jenkins user and Jenkins is headless so it has no ability to type yes to accept the host identification key.

If this is the case you can use the *-o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"* option with scp to auto-accept and allow you to pass here.

Add the -v flag to your scp command and I bet we can see the what is going on in the output.

Here is the man page for scp

https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Good Luck

Comment: Hi still i am facing error i have updated  the question with new error.

Comment: when i used sudo it worked. is it right way to do it. ?

Comment: Really useful, **scp -v** is really helpful and informative.

Answer (score 6):

I found the all mistakes done by me. in this case. as i am new to this i don't aware of many things.so i like to mention the steps which are all done by me to complete this step. if anything i am doing is incorrect or which can be done in different way please suggest. Thanks.

1st was as Darrell mentioned in answers i added the  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" in my SCP command which was like this

```
   scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ubuntu/connec/new_one.pem **/target/*.jar ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu
```

still i faced the error as

```
    Load key "/home/ubuntu/connec/new_one.pem": Permission denied

    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

after searching about the error in google and stackoverflow i found that it's permission issue for the user of Jenkins. when i submit the command in terminal i was using the user as ubuntu but jenkin uses the user as "jenkins". so i have done 2 changes added sudo in my scp command

```
    sudo scp -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/ubuntu/connec/new_one.pem target/*.jar ubuntu@00.00.00.00:/home/ubuntu
```

and then i faced that "Jenkins" user don't have authority to run sudo command so i have edited the file name "VISUDO"

```
 sudo visudo
```

and in last added the line

```
 jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

after that when i ran the pipeline it completed and copied the file...yaayyy.

Still i am wondering am i doing correctly?? any other way is there?

Comment: Ideally you would create a separate key pair for the jenkins user to use and add that to the authorized_keys files for the target host's user. This way Jenkins would not need sudo. If I was going to give you step by step it would look like this:

1. `sudo su - jenkins -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey"`

2. Copy the pub key from /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey.pub to the target machine's authorized_keys file

3. Change your scp command to remove the sudo and reference the new private key - /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/mykey.

Comment: Note - I have not tested these steps, it make take a little tweeking...

Comment: @DarrellPlessas i followed all the steps.. it worked . thank you so much :)

Comment: So you allow Jenkins to become a "superuser" just to be able to access the key-file?? Yeah, because why care about security...

Comment: @DanieleTesta : i agree it is not great solution as i mentioned am not saying is this right way. it is the thing i did that time and worked. can correct the mistake i did. it would be great for all .thanks

Comment: @Pranavadurai How about simply changing the owner of the key-file to "jenkins", so it gets permission to access it? Or at least add the "jenkins" user to the same group as the file?

Comment: The -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no fixed for me